# Javascript hide and remove multiple divs go wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on this page and it isnt done yet. It contains html and javascript only at the moment.

It has to show the radio inputs when the checkbox input has been checked. And at clicking manual, it has to show the div with id custom. And if auto has been clicked it has tonshow the id with "what".

Here is my code:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById('man').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('what').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('custom').style.display = 'none';
};

function showMan() {
  var x = document.getElementById("man");
  x.style.display = "none";
}
function hideMan() {
  var x = document.getElementById("man");
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function showWhat() {
  var x = document.getElementById("what");
  x.style.display = "none";
}
function hideWhat() {
  var x = document.getElementById("what");
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function showCustom() {
  var x = document.getElementById("custom");
  x.style.display = "none";
}
function hideCustom() {
  var x = document.getElementById("custom");
  x.style.display = "block";
}

function calc() {
  if (document.getElementById('check').checked) {
    hideMan();
    showCustom();
  } else {
    showMan();
    hideCustom();
  }
}

function kaas() {
  if (document.getElementById('manual').checked) {
    showWhat();
  } else if (document.getElementById('auto').checked) {
    hideWhat();
  }
}

function countLines(theArea) {
  var theLines = theArea.value.replace((new RegExp(".{" + theArea.cols + "}", "g")), "\n").split("\n");
  if (theLines[theLines.length - 1] == "") theLines.length--;
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = `${theLines.length} account(s)`;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
        Title:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <br>
        <br> Accounts (One per line):
        <br>
        <textarea name="accounts" onKeyUp="countLines(this)" rows="20" cols="40"></textarea>
        <br>
        <p id="count"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        Check all of my accounts (Costs 1$ per 100 accounts)
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkIt" value="1" id="check" onclick="calc();">Yes
        <br>
        <div id="man">
          <input type="radio" name="method" value="manual" checked="checked" id="manual" onclick="kaas();"> Manual check
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="method" value="automatic" id="auto" onclick="kaas();"> Automatic check
          <br>
        </div>
        <div id="custom">
          Give us the url of the site your accounts come from
          <input type="text" name="site">
        </div>
        <div id="what">
          <select name="site">
            <option value="Netflix">Netflix</option>
            <option value="Spotify">Spotify</option>
            <option value="Roblox">Roblox</option>
            <option value="Minecraft">Minecraft</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        One of three columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I am sure there is a easier way to make this work. Sorry for any typos or not marking stuff, but I am on my iPad at the moment. So thats a bit difficult.

Thanks for the help,
Aaron

Comment: Your display values for `showCustom` and `hideCustom` appear to be backwards. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

I just rewrite your code and cleaned it. Please try to code cleaner and write more understandable!

```
<form>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                Title:
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="title">
                <br><br>
                Accounts (One per line):
                <br>
                <textarea name="accounts" onKeyUp="countLines(this)" rows="20" cols="40"></textarea>
                <br>
                <p id="count"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                Check all of my accounts (Costs 1$ per 100 accounts)<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkIt" value="1" id="check" onclick="calc();">Yes
                <br>
                <div id="man">
                    <input type="radio" name="method" value="manual" checked="checked" id="manual" onclick="kaas();"> Manual check<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="method" value="automatic" id="auto" onclick="kaas();"> Automatic check<br>
                </div>
                <div id="custom">
                    Give us the url of the site your accounts come from
                    <input type="text" name="site">
                </div>
                <div id="what">
                    <select name="site">
                        <option value="Netflix">Netflix</option>
                        <option value="Spotify">Spotify</option>
                        <option value="Roblox">Roblox</option>
                        <option value="Minecraft">Minecraft</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                One of three columns
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayTheElement(id, display=false) {
        if (display) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        displayTheElement('man', false);
        displayTheElement('what', false);
        displayTheElement('custom', false);

        calc();
    };

    function calc () {
        if (document.getElementById('check').checked) {
            displayTheElement('man', true);
            displayTheElement('custom', false);

            kaas();
        } else {
            displayTheElement('man', false);
            displayTheElement('custom', true);
        }
    }

    function kaas() {
        if (document.getElementById('manual').checked) {
            displayTheElement('what', true);
        } else {
            displayTheElement('what', false);
        }
    }

    function countLines(theArea){
        var theLines = theArea.value.replace((new RegExp(".{"+theArea.cols+"}","g")),"\n").split("\n");
        if(theLines[theLines.length-1]=="") theLines.length--;
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = `${theLines.length} account(s)`;
    }
</script>
```

But about your mistakes:

1. Your `kaas` methods triggered when you change the value of your related input, but in first loading, it has value (checked or selected), so you must consider it!
2. Your calls were in the wrong hierarchy, just see below codes and try to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, if you click the manual checkbox, it triggers the function kaas. Following the logic backward from there, the 'custom' element never gets displayed. I think you just have to clean up your function calls, they may be mixed up. Try using the browser console and console.log("function kaas is running!"); to trace each function.